# What is the meaning of "$h^{\rightarrow} A \subseteq U$"?

Tags: general-topology, notation

What is the meaning of "$h^{\rightarrow} A \subseteq U$"?

From the context ($h$ is a homeomorphism, $A$ is a set, $U$ is a set), I assume it is the same as $h(A) \subseteq U$. But then, why the author cannot simply write it that way? Am I missing something, have you seen this notation?

Thank you.

[image]

Source: *Van Douwen: Characterizations of βQ and βR*

Comment: What has been the most common notation varies over time and also between different regions. The [Wikipedia page on image of function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Notation_for_image_and_inverse_image) shows that arrow notation as an alternative notation.

Comment: And as to why one might want to use notation like this: $h(A)$ is technically already the notation for the image of a single element of the domain. Using the same notation for the image of a subset is an abuse of notation, though often (not always) a harmless one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, it's a popular (historical now, maybe) notation for $h[A]$, the forward image of a subset under $h$; see [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Notation_for_image_and_inverse_image) e.g. I personally prefer the square brackets notation, because it's potentially less ambiguous then $h(A)$ could be.